# firebase cloud function return json object from batch function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to return to the client Json object ***{mesage: "this is what I want to return"}*** from batch operation... What am I missing here?

```
exports.addMessage3 = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();

    const query = db
        .collection('smtg')
        .where('status', '==', false)
        .limit(1);

    return db
        .runTransaction(async transaction => {
            return transaction
                .get(query)
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    const snapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];

                    if (typeof snapshot === "undefined") {
                        console.log('XXXXXXXX!  ', snapshot);
                        const xyz = myFunction()

                        console.log('XXXXXXXXZZZZZZ!  ', xyz);
                        return { error: "undefined" };
                    }
                    const data = snapshot.data();
                    console.log('LLLoooog!  ', data);
                    transaction.update(snapshot.ref, { status: true });
                    return data;
                })
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Transaction successfully committed!  ', data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Transaction failed:  ', error);
            return error;
        });
});




async function myFunction() {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    let nycRef = db.collection('smtg').doc();
    batch.set(nycRef, { combination: 'ABC11', status: false });

    return batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log('Batched.');
        return {mesage: "this is what I want to return"}
    });
}
```

I case where *snapshot* is undefined I would like to **return myFunction()** and not return { error: "undefined" }

Comment: Can you please add the entire code of your Cloud Function, not only the code of the function that is called by the Cloud Function.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec hope that gives a better view of what I want to achieve...

Comment: I don't think you can call a function returning `batch.commit()` in the middle of a transaction. You can only use the methods of a Transaction: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html. Also, it is a bit difficult to understand your exact goal by reading your code. You may add some comments along the code to help us understanding your goal. Also, why do you use a batched write with only one doc?

Comment: Gosh... you are right... What the heck am I thinking? I totally lost that I am in the middle of transaction... However, batch.commit() does work, it does create new instances... the Real question is if what I am doing is ok and valid!

Comment: The promise returned from the top level callback must resolve to the data you want to send to the client.

Comment: In any case, every time `snapshot` is undefined, `myFunction()` is successfully performed, but in your code what you are always returning is `{ error: "undefined" }`, not the result of your function.

Comment: well, I can't return myFunction(), I did try that. What correct would be is to call myFunction() from `.then((data)` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I can't call batch in the middle of the transaction I can call it from `.then((data)` block. So what I did was:

```
exports.addMessage3 = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();

    const query = db
        .collection('smtg')
        .where('status', '==', false)
        .limit(1);

    return db
        .runTransaction(async transaction => {
            return transaction
                .get(query)
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    const snapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];
                    if (typeof snapshot === "undefined") {
                        return snapshot;
                    }
                    const data = snapshot.data();
                    console.log('LLLoooog!  ', data);
                    transaction.update(snapshot.ref, { status: true });
                    return data;
                })
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Transaction successfully committed!  ', data);
            if (typeof data === "undefined") {
                    return myFunction();
            }
            return data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Transaction failed:  ', error);
            return error;
        });
});




async function myFunction() {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    let nycRef = db.collection('smtg').doc();
    batch.set(nycRef, { combination: 'ABC11', status: false });

    return batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log('Batched.');
        return {mesage: "this is what I want to return"}
    });
}
```